# Getting 'TooBig' Memcachier exception on a Django Rest Framework response on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, memcached

I have a Django site on Heroku, which uses Memcachier's free tier as a basic cache across the whole site. It works fine.

I've just started trying out Django Rest Framework to create a read-only JSON API, and that works fine too, except... one or more API URLs generate 'TooBig' exceptions from Memcachier, even though the response isn't very large (e.g. 20-30 KB):

```
MemcachedError: 

TooBig
No exception message supplied
```

I'm puzzled as to why this is happening, given the small size, and not sure how to fix it. Maybe I've misunderstood something about how memcached works.

Comment: Are you using pylibmc?
In pylibmc this means the value is too large (>1MB). See [here](https://github.com/lericson/pylibmc/blob/14f66d73ea9d4ce58ca1c03b23c62367923568bf/src/_pylibmcmodule.h#L180) and [here](http://docs.libmemcached.org/client_errors/MEMCACHED_E2BIG.html)

Comment: @SaschaTrifunovic I am, but I don't know why that error is occurring when the response is so small.

Comment: What do you mean by small responses? This error happens during a `set` command, i.e., when you try to store a value in memcached, not when you `get` a value (as there are no >1MB values in your MemCachier cache). Are you sure the key+value that you are trying to store is smaller than 1MB?

Comment: @SaschaTrifunovic Maybe I'm misunderstanding how it works! I assumed that because the 'page' that's being cached is very small when requested by a browser (I just tried one that generates the error, and it's 5.39 KB of HTML) it couldn't be greater than >1MB when sent to the cache.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: You request a page (via browser) and this causes this error to appear on server. If this is correct, and the rendered HTML you are caching is indeed small as you say, then requesting your page causes Django to store something else that is too large in memcached. Could that be?

Comment: Can you share some code relevant to this error?

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I assumed Memcachier only cached the resulting HTML but perhaps I've misunderstood how it works! I'm looking into what else might be unnecessarily large... SQL queries etc.

Comment: I *think* I've fixed it. Some of the API detail views were fetching a lot of related objects, using the `HyperlinkedRelatedField()` serializer. I realised that this fetched ALL of the objects' columns, even though only their `pk`s were needed. This was a lot of data (not 10MB, but still). I've now restricted which columns are fetched from the DB and this seems to work! https://stackoverflow.com/a/49819377/250962

Answer (score 0):

You should increase memcached limits.

See here:
https://django-cachalot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limits.html#memcached

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/ha-memcached-cmdline-options.html