# In Django Rest Framework, how to restrict fields fetched with a RelatedField Serializer relation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Taking this example of a Serializer [from the DRF docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield):

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    tracks = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        view_name='track-detail'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

When DRF does the query to fetch all the `track`s for a particular `album`, the SQL generated selects *all* of each `track`'s columns. How would I restrict it to only request specific columns, e.g. the `pk` that would be used for the Hyperlinks to each track in the response?

(Why? Because there might be a *lot* of tracks returned and each one have a *lot* of data in its row in the database, which could be a lot of unnecessary data returned.)

Comment: Try to use SerializerMethodField http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield ? So you can manage the Queryset and build it like you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does it...

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

from myapp.models import Album


class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    tracks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')

    def get_tracks(self, instance):
        "Returns a list of URLs for Tracks' API detail views"

        request = self.context.get('request')

        tracks = []

        for track in instance.tracks.values('pk'):
            tracks.append(reverse(
                                'track-detail',
                                kwargs={'pk': track['pk']},
                                request=request
                            ))

        return tracks
```

We're manually creating the result of a `HyperlinkedRelatedField()` (returning a list of URLs to the track's API detail pages), but restricting the data fetched from the database using `values()` in the queryset.

This assumes that the `track-detail` URL pattern has a parameter of `pk`.

Replacing a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField()` is even simpler. Replace the `get_tracks()` method above with this:

```
    def get_tracks(self, instance):
        "Returns a list of Track IDs"
        return instance.tracks.values_list('pk', flat=True)
```

Thanks to @jmny for heading me towards using `SerializerMethodField()`.

Comment: Note: Originally I used `reverse_lazy()` to generate the URLs, rather than `reverse()` but when Django's caching is turned on (Django's `locmem.LocMemCache` or memcached with `PyLibMCCache`), this generated errors when results were going to be cached: "cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object" or "cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to build yourself  the queryset and use [value_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    tracks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_tracks(self, instance):
        return TracK.objects.filter(album=self).values_list('id', flat=True)


    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('album_name', 'artist', 'tracks')
```

Comment: I can see where you're going but... if I return `instance.tracks.values_list(flat=True)` then it's just a list of ALL the data for ALL the relevant tracks. I can get `instance.tracks.values('pk')` which is the data I need, but then I'd need to construct a list of API URLs using DRF's `reverse_lazy()` method, and that requires the `request` object, which isn't accessible here. Hmm.

Comment: I forget the more important : values_list(flat=True) => values_list('id', flat=True) , sorry :)

Comment: Ah, good point! That would work for just returning the `id`s of the Tracks, so it's good for the simpler case, but not getting all the URLs. I'll amend the simple version of my answer.